# How to label every nth row of a pandas dataframe by an incremental value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple problem (hopefully!). and i am overly complicating it. Maybe there is a one liner out there; I have a dataframe that contains lets say 10 rows and I want to label rows in such a way it looks like col B. Every 4th row has an different label.

```
Row B
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   2
6   2
7   2
8   2
9   3
10  3
```

I tried iterating by dataframe position and ended up complicating it.

```
num =4 
id=1
    def label_id(x,num,id):
        if x > num:
          id=id+1
          label=id           
          num=num*id
        else:
            label = id
            id=id
        return label
    id=1
    for i in range(len(df)):
        df.iat[i,1] = df.apply(label_id(df.iat[i,0],num,id),axis=1)
```

i get an error TypeError: ("'int' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0'). I am sure i am overthinking this. Any help?

Comment: `df['B'] = np.arange(len (df)) // n + 1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `numpy` `divmod`

```
f['B']=np.divmod(np.arange(len(df)),4)[0]+1
df
   Row  B
0    1  1
1    2  1
2    3  1
3    4  1
4    5  2
5    6  2
6    7  2
7    8  2
8    9  3
9   10  3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use expanding:

```
df.Row.expanding().apply(lambda x: (len(x)+3)//4, raw=True).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.repeat`

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'Row': range(10)})
df['B'] = np.repeat(range(math.ceil(df.shape[0]/4)),4)[:df.shape[0]] + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `repeat` function

```
import math
df['B'] = (np.repeat(range(math.ceil(df.shape[0]/4)),4))[:df.shape[0]] + 1
```

Comment: Any reason why your answer is exactly as @fmarm? Their's seem to be a couple of minutes earlier than yours.